# How to make checkbox length nil after fucntion

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few checkboxes and a button that is used to send the selected to trash. 
My functionality to select and send them to trash works. But my button to send them to trash, should appear only when checkboxes are selected and disappear when they are moved to trash. But my button doesn't disappear since my checkbox value is not reset to zero on deleting. Any idea how to reset my checkbox length after moving the files to trash. 
My code is below,

```
$('input[name=myfile_select_id]').change(function() {
    console.log("Touched");
    console.log($('input[name=myfile_select_id]:checked').length);
    if ($('input[name=myfile_select_id]:checked').length > 1) {
        // one or more checkboxes are checked
        $("#trash-select").show();
    } else {
        // no checkboxes are checked
        $("#trash-select").hide();
    }
});

$("#trash-select").click(function() {
    console.log("CLI");
    var selectedFiles = $('input[name=myfile_select_id]:checked');
    var checkValues = selectedFiles.map(function() {
        return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    if (confirm("Are you sure, you want to move these files to trashcan?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/myfiles/multiple_select',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                myfile_ids: checkValues
            },
            success: function(data) {}
        }).done(function() {
            selectedFiles.each(function(index) {
                console.log("I'm done");
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.log("not passed");
    }
});
```

My xyz.html.erb file

```
<div class="File--Select">
                <%= check_box_tag "myfile_select_id", myfile.id , false, :id => "myfile-select-#{myfile_path(myfile).to_s.split('/')[2]}"  , :class => "file-select" %>
</div>  
<div class="pull-right">
  <%= button_tag :id =>"trash-select", :class => "btn btn-sm btn-danger", :style => "display:none" do %>
  <span class="" aria-hidden="true"></span> Move to Trash
  <% end %> &nbsp;
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated. TIA.

Comment: can you give me a fiddle?

Comment: My code is in ruby, and the paths are linked to local DB. Is it possible to give it in fiddle?

Comment: can you give me your html code?

Comment: i think you want press trash button remove checked item row. is it write?

Comment: Updated with HTML File.

Comment: $('table tr').has('input[name="myfile_select_id"]:checked').remove() use this line  in ajax done function

Comment: i have posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this. may helpful for you

```
function reset(selectedFiles){ 
   if(selectedFiles.length < 1) { $("#trash-select").hide();} }//can you call this function in ajax done function once removed the checkedbox row.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should programmatically trigger `change event after checkboxes removal.

```
//You don't need each
selectedFiles.closest('tr').remove();
//Trgger cgnage event
$('input[name=myfile_select_id]').change();
```

Comment: Doesn't really do the needful. The button persists.

Answer (score 0):

need to hide the button on .done as the change event is not firing on tr removal.

```
 .done(function() {
        selectedFiles.each(function(index) {
            console.log("I'm done");
            $(this).closest('tr').remove();
         // hide button on done
            $("#trash-select").hide();
 });
```